# how to use Multiautocompletetext with a large database/cursor

Tags: android

I have a database with 400k records in it and I want to use it with a MultiAutoCompleteText.

One possible way is to load all those records in a cursor and use a CursorAdapter with our MultiAutoCompleteText view. However it seems very inefficient to me and I wonder if there's a more efficient way, so that I don't have to load all the records altogether.

For example one way is to consider the first letter entered by the user and load only those records starting with that letter. However, this way we have to change the cursor on every new word and deliver the new cursor to MultiAutoCompleteText which I don't know how.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> 400k records have to retrieve for each and every time from database is
>   inefficient... and u can achieve this...
>
> It is better to create a service for loading data from the
>   database..... make that service as singleTon as

```
public class RecordsLoadingService extends Service {
    private ArrayList<Record> records;
    private static RecordsLoading recordsLoading;
    public static RecordsLoadingService getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    public void onCreate() {
        if (instance == null) {         
            instance = this;
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<Clock> getAllRecords() {
        return records;
    }
    public void setRecordsLoadingListener(RecordsLoading recordsLoading) {
        this.recordsLoading = recordsLoading;
    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        LoadData loadData = new LoadData();
        loadData.execute("");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Clock>> {
        protected ArrayList<Records> doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(records!=null){
             //retrive records from database
            }
            return records;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Clock> clocks) {
            super.onPostExecute(clocks);
            if (recordsLoading != null) {
                recordsLoading.onLoadingCompletedListener(clocks);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

> retrieve data in activity as..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RecordsLoading {
    private ArrayList<Record> records=new ArrayList<Records>;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //take one progress Bar in layout and make visible
        setContentView(R.layout.id);
        if (RecordsLoadingService.getAllClocks() != null) {
                onLoadingCompletedListener(citiesLoadingService.getAllClocks());
            } else {
                if (RecordsLoadingService.getInstance() != null) {
                    RecordsLoadingService.getInstance().setCitiesLoadingListener(
                            this);
                } else {
                    Intent startLoading = new Intent(this,
                            RecordsLoadingService.class);
                    startService(startLoading);
                    isStarted = true;
                }
            }
    }
    protected void onResume() {
        if (isStarted) {
            if (RecordsLoadingService.getInstance() != null) {
                RecordsLoadingService.getInstance().setRecordsLoadingListener(
                        this);
            }
        }
        super.onResume();
    }
    public void onLoadingCompletedListener(ArrayList<Records> records) {
        this.records=records;
        initAdapter();
    }
    public void initAdapter(){
    //make that progress Bar in layout and make invisible
    //create adapter for MultiAutoCompleteText and pass these records.....
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean i need to have ALL records loaded anyway? either in a service or wherever?

Comment: the above snippet given loads the data from the database when the app starts for the first time...and used those records for the lifetime(even if those records are garbageCollected service will reload records from database)
start that service in main screen of your app if the records is not there then it will load else it will not load...u can get those records from RecordsLoading callback as shown in the above  mainactivity screen

Comment: Thank you, but actually this approach is the one I've been trying to avoid. I mean having all those records loaded in memory all the time. Thank you for your time anyway.